# What is the meaning of using combination of detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject and [NSThread Start]

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, core-foundation

I am using below code where in method `startThread` if I am using `detachNewThreadSelector` method, it blocks my UI but when I use to make object of NSThread and call `start` method and in that I called `run` method it is not blocking my UI.

What I am not getting is `detachNewThreadSelector` will run in background so it should not block my UI.then why so in my case?

and what is with `start` method and `NSThread` object? will it run in background or main thread?

I have search so many articles and StackOverFlow questions but not get in which senario actually these Threads workout

```
 -(void)startThread
    {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        //NSThread *myThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(run:) object:nil];
        //[myThread start];
        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(run:) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
        [pool release];
    }

-(void)run:(id)param
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    while (threadProgressView.progress < 1) {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.25];
        [self updateProgressBar];
        //[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(updateProgressBar) toTarget:self withObject:nil];


    }
    threadStartButton.hidden = NO;
    [pool release];
}
-(void)updateProgressBar
{
    NSLog(@"In update progress bar");
    float actual = [threadProgressView progress];
    threadValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",actual];
    threadProgressView.progress = actual + 0.025;

}
```

Comment: What are you doing in updateProgressBar method ?

Comment: I am updating label value according to progressbar progess and showing progressbar progressing

Comment: always update UI on main thread.

Comment: still i am not getting what should be the exact flow? what will be the effect if i omit `startThread` method and on any button click i call `run` method and in run method I call `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; `

Comment: Updating the UI means calling `updateProgressBar` method, on main theread blocking my other UI elements and also not showing actual update of progressview.It just shows 0 and directly to 1

Comment: also your threadStartButton.hidden = NO; on main thread

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6224/discussion-between-0x8badf00d-and-roshni)